Concatenating and organizing Several Muti-Index dataframes
I am attempting to combine several dataframes originating from different excel worksheets and organize them according to their respective indices. These different dataframes represent different vehicle classes. For example, I can have:
In [28]: df_Cars_&_Light_Goods.head()
Out[28]:
                 Eastbound            Northbound            Southbound
                Left Thru Right     U-Turn Thru Right     U-Turn Left Thru
Start Time
07:00              0    0     0          0  475    17          0   43  761
07:15              0    0     0          0  558    19          1   43  834
07:30              0    0     0          0  577    28          0   37  833

In [32]: df_Buses.head()
Out[32]:
                 Eastbound            Northbound            Southbound
                Left Thru Right     U-Turn Thru Right     U-Turn Left Thru
Start Time
07:00              0    0     0          0   24     1          0    0   14
07:15              0    0     0          0   14     2          0    2   13
07:30              0    0     0          0   35     2          0    0   18

I have tried concatenating them using
df_comb = pd.concat([df_tcc[key] for key in keys], ignore_index=True, axis= 1, keys= keys).sort_index(axis = 1)

where 'keys' is a list of all the dataframe names (df_Buses, df_Cars_&_Light_Goods, etc.). In addition, I only used the first column as my index (df = df.set_index(df.columns[0], drop = True)) to organize the timestamps. The above just results in a mere join of all the dataframes which are unorganized. In addition, it loses the multi index labeling and results in a simple numbering
system.
This is the expected outcome.
I feel like I'm missing something with setting the index before concatenating, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Can you provide a [mre] as code (rather than text version of the inputs)?

If you use ignore_index=True, you will lose the MultiIndex.
You should probably use:
df_comb = (pd.concat({key: df_tcc[key] for key in keys}, axis=1)
             .reorder_levels([2,0,1], axis=1)
             .sort_index(axis=1)
          )


I tried your code, and it did work (thanks!), however, an empty row is now inserted below the column headers. Is there any way to organize the index similar to my previous outcome? In addition, I noticed that the index (at the same level) are organized alphabetically. Can you change the order of the index to match whatever order you want them to be (say, a predetermined list)?

Update: FIgured out how to change the order, just need assistance on how to sort the index

@Ace_1918 yes you would need to use an ordered Categorical.

Could you clarify what you mean by that? I believe the gap/blank row between the col headers and the data itself is preventing further indexing.

@Ace_1918 to be clear, there is no gap/blank row (in pandas), this jump is only added when exporting the data to csv/excel. Can you please provide a [mre] of the inputs (as code) and the exact expected output? I'll then update the answer.

thanks for the response. Actually, it turned out to be an error with how I was indexing my dataframe later in the code, which I was able to resolve. Everything works now, thanks!
